# How can I stack annotations on top of each other with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to generate a figure with a vector decomposition along two axes (see example below), and I'm using `matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate()` ([docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html?highlight=annotate#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate)) to do so. It looks like matplotlib automatically moves the tips of the small red arrows so that they don't fall on the larger black ones. I've tried looking at the docs but I can't find a solution. I will also accept other libraries as an answer.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

# Square aspect ratio
ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.set(xlim=[-1,1], ylim=[-1,1], xticks=[], yticks=[])

# Draw image
ax.annotate('f', (-1, 0), (1, 0), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<-'))
ax.annotate('s', (0, -1), (0, 1), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<-'))
ax.annotate('', (0, 0), (.5, .5), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<-', color='r'))    
ax.annotate('', (0, 0), (0, .5), arrowprops=dict(color='r',arrowstyle='<-', ls='--'))
ax.annotate('', (0, 0), (.5, 0), arrowprops=dict(color='r',arrowstyle='<-', ls='--'))
```

This code generates [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5tZ4.png)

Comment: try setting the shrink parameters to 0: `arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<-', shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0)`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @tmdavison, but that did't do anything. I'm accepting Diziet Asahi's answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like this has something to do with the alignment of the arrow and the annotation text. I'm not sure if it's a bug, or if it was made on purpose, though.

Compare:

```
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(8,4))
for ax in [ax1,ax2]:
    ax.set(xlim=[-1,1], ylim=[-0.1,0.1], xticks=[], yticks=[])
ax1.annotate('A', (-1, 0), (1, 0), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<-', color='k'))
ax1.annotate('', (-1, 0), (1, 0), arrowprops=dict(color='r',arrowstyle='<-', ls='--'))

ax2.annotate('', (-1, 0), (1, 0), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<-', color='k'))
ax2.annotate('', (-1, 0), (1, 0), arrowprops=dict(color='r',arrowstyle='<-', ls='--'))
```

[image]

My solution for you would thus be to remove the text from the arrow annotations that you have and add it with a separate annotation or `ax.text()`